# Had been - sequence of tenses

Tags: sequence-of-tenses

Is this sentence grammatically correct? "I have also met outstanding educators who had been incredibly supportive to each other"

Comment: Hello Lyudmyla, Can you have another look at the [tour] and [ask]  The best questions provoke answers that explain How and Why.  A question "is the sentence correct" doesn't do this.  Can you explain why you have a doubt about this sentence. What is it about the tenses that you are worried about?

Comment: Note too that it's possible to construct numerous sentences that are grammatically  correct but completely unnatural. That's to say that native speakers would never use them. They are not idiomatic. PS **incredibly** is the vogue, all-purpose, utterly meaningless modifier that trips off millions of thoughtless tongues!

Comment: @RonaldSole I do not agree that the indicated sentence is unnatural. The structure is commonplace. “i myself have met people who had been to Antarctica.” The problem with the sentence is that it is hard to imagine a context in which this particular sentence makes sense.

Comment: @JeffMorrow I welcome comments that prompt me to think about an issue. If you **have met** people who **had been** to Antarctica, have they since died?  Or is it just that they **have been** there. (PS Don't you hate the universal **incredibly** to mean **very/extremely**?)

Comment: @RonaldSole I probably was picking nits. The given sentence is difficult to imagine being uttered by someone **competent** in English, but it is not impossible to imagine. My real point is that grammar is the servant of meaning. Worry about meaning before worrying about grammar. As for my sentence, all it **necessarily** means is that the people I met were not in Antarctica when I met them despite preceding time in Antarctica. The form is valid. As for intensifiers, they **are** grossly overused (including by me as “grossly” demonstrates). That is why real writing is re-writing.

Answer (score 0):

It is grammatically correct if the educators were supportive but are not supportive now.  If the educators have not stopped being supportive, either use:
"I have also met outstanding educators who have been incredibly supportive to each other"
or
"I had also met outstanding educators who had been incredibly supportive to each other"

Answer (score 0):

The sentence is grammatically correct. And, in a certain context, it would be natural. But you have provided no context. Whether it correctly expresses the intended thought in a likely context is a completely different issue.

First, the present perfect tense seems to be used here merely for emphasis rather than to imply recency or current relevance.

Second, as pointed out in the answer of DanG, the meaning of that sentence is that these paragons were mutually supportive at one or more times **previous** to the instant when you met them. The clear implication is that they were no longer mutually supportive when you **did** meet them.

What controls is meaning. If you mean to emphasize that you met educators who were mutually supportive at one time but later ceased to be, then the sentence is not only grammatical, but also, and much more importantly, apt. If that is **NOT** your meaning, then the sentence is wrong **despite** being grammatical.